# How add border bottom to last div if there will be additional div?

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to add border-bottom only to last div if there will be an additional div. Not to additional, but the last one before additional. How to implement it? This is code:

```
<div className={`${classes.card_list}`}>
                            <div className={`${classes.card_list_title}`}>
                                <p>Əlavə olunan tarix</p>
                                <p>Kart</p>
                            </div>

                            <div className={`${classes.card_body}`}>
                                <div>
                                    <p>21.02.2023</p>
                                    <p>11.25</p>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <h3>4098****5656</h3>
                                    <p>Leo</p>
                                </div>
                                <div className={`${classes.card_type}`}>{visa}</div>
                                <div>
                                    <button>{threeDots}</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a parent container around those divs then the combination of `:not` and `:last-child` should work:

```css
    .container div:not(:last-child) {
      border-bottom:1px dashed #ff0000;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

or you can specify the class instead of **div**.